# sonarqube 6.6: Unrecoverable indexation failures "IllegalArgumentException "name" is too large

Tags: elasticsearch, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

After upgrading to SonarQube 6.6 the tests index cannot be build.
Error message

```
[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DocValuesField "name" is too large, must be <= 32766]
```

Already tried to delete the es5 folder with all indexes. Any ideas how to find these documents that should be added into the index. Or can we set a different fields schema where we can truncate or ignore this field?

```
2017.10.27 10:00:47 INFO  web[][o.s.s.n.NotificationDaemon] Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
2017.10.27 10:00:47 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Indexing of type [rules/activeRule] ...
2017.10.27 10:00:48 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Indexing of type [rules/activeRule] done | time=1922ms
2017.10.27 10:00:49 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Indexing of types [rules/ruleExtension],[rules/rule] ...    
2017.10.27 10:00:52 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Indexing of types [rules/ruleExtension],[rules/rule] done | time=3233ms
2017.10.27 10:00:52 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Indexing of type [users/user] ...
2017.10.27 10:00:52 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Indexing of type [users/user] done | time=384ms
2017.10.27 10:00:52 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Indexing of type [components/component] ...
2017.10.27 10:00:59 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Indexing of type [components/component] done | time=6398ms
2017.10.27 10:00:59 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Indexing of type [views/view] ...
2017.10.27 10:00:59 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Indexing of type [views/view] done | time=142ms
2017.10.27 10:00:59 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Indexing of type [issues/issue] ...
2017.10.27 10:01:01 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Indexing of type [issues/issue] done | time=2619ms
2017.10.27 10:01:01 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Indexing of types [components/authorization],[issues/authorization],[projectmeasures/authorization] ...
2017.10.27 10:01:05 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Indexing of types [components/authorization],[issues/authorization],[projectmeasures/authorization] done | time=4092ms
2017.10.27 10:01:05 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Indexing of type [tests/test] ...
2017.10.27 10:01:10 ERROR web[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] index [tests], type [test], id [AV9chemx3phqC53p-evV], message [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DocValuesField "name" is too large, must be <= 32766]
2017.10.27 10:01:10 ERROR web[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] index [tests], type [test], id [AV9chemy3phqC53p-evi], message [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DocValuesField "name" is too large, must be <= 32766]
2017.10.27 10:01:10 ERROR web[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] index [tests], type [test], id [AV9chemw3phqC53p-eu-], message [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DocValuesField "name" is too large, must be <= 32766]
2017.10.27 10:01:10 ERROR web[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] index [tests], type [test], id [AV9chemy3phqC53p-evW], message [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DocValuesField "name" is too large, must be <= 32766]
2017.10.27 10:01:10 ERROR web[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] index [tests], type [test], id [AV9chemv3phqC53p-eum], message [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DocValuesField "name" is too large, must be <= 32766]
2017.10.27 10:01:10 ERROR web[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] index [tests], type [test], id [AV9chemv3phqC53p-eul], message [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DocValuesField "name" is too large, must be <= 32766]
2017.10.27 10:01:10 ERROR web[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] index [tests], type [test], id [AV9chemv3phqC53p-eux], message [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DocValuesField "name" is too large, must be <= 32766]
2017.10.27 10:01:10 ERROR web[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] index [tests], type [test], id [AV9chemx3phqC53p-evK], message [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DocValuesField "name" is too large, must be <= 32766]
2017.10.27 10:01:10 ERROR web[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] index [tests], type [test], id [AV9chemy3phqC53p-evh], message [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DocValuesField "name" is too large, must be <= 32766]
2017.10.27 10:01:10 ERROR web[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] index [tests], type [test], id [AV9chemx3phqC53p-evJ], message [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DocValuesField "name" is too large, must be <= 32766]
2017.10.27 10:01:10 ERROR web[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] index [tests], type [test], id [AV9chemw3phqC53p-eu9], message [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DocValuesField "name" is too large, must be <= 32766]
2017.10.27 10:01:10 ERROR web[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] index [tests], type [test], id [AV9chemw3phqC53p-euy], message [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DocValuesField "name" is too large, must be <= 32766]
2017.10.27 10:01:10 ERROR web[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] index [tests], type [test], id [AV9chenH3phqC53p-e2o], message [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DocValuesField "name" is too large, must be <= 32766]
2017.10.27 10:01:10 ERROR web[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] index [tests], type [test], id [AV9chenG3phqC53p-e2m], message [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DocValuesField "name" is too large, must be <= 32766]
2017.10.27 10:01:16 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unrecoverable indexation failures
at org.sonar.server.es.IndexingListener$1.onFinish(IndexingListener.java:39)
at org.sonar.server.es.BulkIndexer.stop(BulkIndexer.java:117)
at org.sonar.server.test.index.TestIndexer.indexOnStartup(TestIndexer.java:75)
at org.sonar.server.es.IndexerStartupTask.indexUninitializedTypes(IndexerStartupTask.java:68)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
at org.sonar.server.es.IndexerStartupTask.execute(IndexerStartupTask.java:55)
at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup$1.doPrivileged(PlatformLevelStartup.java:91)
at org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:45)
at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.start(PlatformLevelStartup.java:87)
at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:196)
at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.access$400(Platform.java:46)
at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$1.lambda$doRun$1(Platform.java:121)
at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$AutoStarterRunnable.runIfNotAborted(Platform.java:371)
at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$1.doRun(Platform.java:121)
at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$AutoStarterRunnable.run(Platform.java:355)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Look like issue [SONAR-9796](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-9796) is not solved?